# Identifying letters up to homotopy

Tags: algebraic-topology

I already identified the letters of the alphabet up to homeomorphism and the useful characteristic was cut-points and their preservation under homeomorphism. As a visual representation you can imagine trying to bend the letters in $R^2$ until they form the new letter you're trying to take in their equivalence class.

Is there a similar invariant I can use for homotopic equivalence? What about another visual way to see the letter's equivalence?

Thanks.

Comment: The fundamental group is a good tool to distinguish non-equivalent letters. You can retract antennae, so $A$ is homotopy equivalent to $\Delta$, which is homeomorphic to $O$, for example.

Comment: Okay I see, thank you!

Comment: Read the first few pages of Chapter 0 http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATchapters.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very roughly speaking, two objects are homotopy equivalent if they both result from "squishing" some larger object. So if you are a visual learner, grab some clay and squish it into the letters!

BTW, according to me, you should get the following sets of homotopy equivalent letters: $$\{A,R,D,O,P,Q\},\{B\},\{C,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z\}$$

Comment: So as opposed to bending in homeomorphism equivalence, now if I have an appendage or something I can squish it into itself?

Comment: @EgoKilla Yes, exactly!